# Calculating N for DFT

Tags: dft

We want to compute an N-point DFT of a one-second duration compact disc (CD) audio signal x[n], whose sample rate is $f_s = 44.1Khz$ with a DFT sampling of 1 Hz.

(a) What is the number of necessary x[n] time samples N?

(b) what is the time duration of the x[n] sequence measured in seconds?

---

I said:

$f_s = 44100 hz$
$f_o = 1 hz$

(a) $N = f_s / f_o  = 44100 / 1 = 44100?$

(b) $T_s * N = (1/f_S) * N = (1/44100) * 44100 = 1 sec?$

Could I call $f_0$ the fundamental frequency of the DFT and assert that this frequency (1 hertz) corresponds exactly to a time period equal to the length of the x[n] sample range (1 second)?

Is that the definition of the fundamental frequency of DFT...that its the frequency corresponding to the entire sample time period of x[n] of length N...which also happens to be the smallest frequency increment of DFT of which there are exact N frequency buckets that add up to the sampling frequency.

Comment: for one second of one channel of a CD would be 44100 samples.  then $N \ge$ 44100.  i might suggest rounding up to the next power of 2 to $N=$ 65536 and zero-padding the difference.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,   Incidentally, do fft library function generally right pad zeros until it gets a power of 2 size?  I was just using dft... but fft seems easier since its a built in library function.

Comment: there are a few different FFT libs, so the answer to your question is neither *"yes"* nor *"no"* in general.  specifically for [FFTW (which is considered the state-of-the-art)](http://www.fftw.org/), the answer is *"no"*.  Listed in their feature set: **"Arbitrary-size transforms. (Sizes with small prime factors are best, but FFTW uses O(N log N) algorithms even for prime sizes.)"**  And using just the DFT that you can code yourself is fine if you're doing it for a small $N$, but it becomes a real problem once $N\ge4096$.